# How to use Magento Functionalities(Login, Payment, Order Management) inside cakephp?

Tags: php, magento, cakephp

I am using Magento and cakephp applications. I wanted to have same login for both applications. 
For Example: Use Magento Login Module without any Layout inside Cakephp, access database to get details of  registered users, authentication if not registered, Create account functionality. 
Layout from cakephp application and functionality from Magento.

I tried integrating Magento features like login customer based on email, get login user details, Cart items, add product to magento cart, update product details etc. Posted the code which I tried in gist, But not able make entire login and payment funcionality from cakephp.
Gistlink:https://gist.github.com/kanampalli/692edcf70ca48d02a532f410ddf219be

But not able to integrate entire login functionality and Payment through magento once order placed from cakephp application. How to get session and update in both application?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to [Magento SOAP API](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html).